# Error initializing SparkContext:SparkException

Tags: apache-spark

I am running the below spark-java code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
public class Resource{
public static void main(String[] args) {
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("cust data");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hiveSQLContext = new    org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(jsc.sc());
DataFrame df = hiveSQLContext.sql(" select * from emprecord");
df.registerTempTable("mytempTable");//creating temptable
hiveSQLContext.sql("create table xyz as select * from mytempTable");//inserting into hie table
jsc.close(
}
}
```

## Compile snippet as below:

```
 [harsha@hdp-poc1 SparkworkingJars]$ javac -cp $CLASSPATH Resource.java
warning: /home/harsha/SparkworkingJars/spark-core_2.11-    1.6.1.jar(org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContextVarargsWorkaround.class):     major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this    compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.1 warning
```

## RUN snippet as below:

```
    [harsha@hdp-poc1 SparkworkingJars]$ java -cp $CLASSPATH Resource
16/05/24 10:50:04 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/05/24 10:50:05 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop     library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/05/24 10:50:05 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your     configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>    (JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at Resource.main(Resource.java:15)
    16/05/24 10:50:05 INFO spark.SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL     must be set in your configuration
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>    (JavaSparkContext.scala:59)
    at Resource.main(Resource.java:15)
```

Please help me resolving the issue related to org.apache.spark.SparkException .

Answer (score 10):

You need to specify master URL while launching a spark application via spark-submit. You can either add `--master local[*]` as a command line argument (if you want to run in standalone local mode (or other `--master` options for running on yarn or mesos). Reference - [Submitting Spark applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

Otherwise, you could also specify master in your program.

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("cust data").setMaster("local[*]");
```

But preferred way is the former, as you can launch your same job to different types of clusters if you keep the master outside of your source code.